# can't pass http body/data from react fronted to django rest api, always get empty body/data

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I've got issue with passing data in http body from react to DRF.
I've got code for fetch:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/quality_api/all',{
            method:'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'Authorization':'Token xxxxxxxxx'
            },
            
            params: {
                testData: 'test data',
                pageNum: 1
            },
            data: {
                testData: 'test data',
                pageNum: 1
            },
            
        })
```

In my view I've got:

```
class UsersApiView4(APIView):
    def get(self, request, type_in, format=None):
        print(request.user)
        print(request.data)
        print(request.query_params)
        print(request.body)
```

I'd like to get to the data or params in get method of my view to do some action based on them before sending the data back to frontend.
The problem is I always get empty dict for data, query_params.

No idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

After half a day looking for cause of problem I found that fetch just doesn't support request body but accept params passed in url :(